# Speech input for visually impaired users without the need to tap the screen

Tags: ios, accessibility, speech-to-text

We're working on a app for blind and visually impaired users. We've been experimenting with a third party library to get spoken user input and convert it to text, which we then parse as commands to control the app. The problem is that the word recognition is not very good and certainly not anywhere near as good as what iOS uses to get voice input on a text field.

I'd like to experiment with that, but our users are mostly unable to tap a text field, then hit the mic button on the popup keyboard, then hit the done button or even dismiss any of it. I'm not even sure how they can deal with a single tap on the whole screen, it might be too difficult for some. So, I'd like to automate that for them, but I don't see anything in the docs that indicates it is possible. So, is it even possible, and if so, what's the proper way to do it so that it passes verification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the iOS dictation is to sign up yourself through Nuance: http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/ - it's expensive, because it's the best. Presumably, Apple's contract prevents them from exposing an API.

The built in iOS accessibility features allow immobilized users to access dictation (and other keyboard buttons) through tools like VoiceOver and Assistive Touch. It may not be worth reinventing this if your users might be familiar with these tools.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but Nuance is just too expensive for an indie free app. And their dev tier looks to be too restrictive for actual development, I'd guess we'd use all that capacity easily. The reason we are building this app is to overcome the shortcomings of the existing solutions. As good as they are, and iOS is well ahead of everyone else, the primary problem being that they are tedious to use, things a sighted person does in seconds take a long time with the existing tools. What I'd like to do is try driving the existing text input with something that does not require any precise touches.

Comment: We're currently evaluating Dragon's framework for iOS:  http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/ which has better pricing. I thought Nuance and Dragon were the same, but there is possibly some difference I have not detected yet. I'll post more when we are done evaluating the framework. Right now all I can say is that it looks like the best solution.

Comment: @FranK. Thanks for the update.  Please let me know; I'm curious what you decide.

Comment: We've decided to structure the code to allow us to use iSpeech or Dragon with a build setting since they have similar APIs. As I mentioned, the app needs to get functional ASAP and the rest of the team are all new guys and we only have a few months, so this seems like a better short term solution. We'll eat the fees in the very short term hoping the app gets traction. If it does, we'll dig deeper and see if we can get a better deal or use something "free" like CMUSphinx, or find funding to help pay the bills.

Comment: Both answers pointed me away from trying to trick the system into using the keyboard, which is the right answer to avoid hassles getting into the App Store. But Aaron's answer was first and also got us to reconsider Nuance and led us to find the better pricing, which is the most expedient thing for us to do now. If I could share the checkmark I'd split it, but I can't. Thanks to both answerers for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The solution for you is to implement a keyword spotting so that the speech recognition will be activated with the keyword instead of button tap. After that you can record commands/text and recognize them with any service you need. Something like "Ok google" activation on Motorola X.

There are several keyword activation libraries for iOS, one possible solution is OpenEars based on the open source speech recogntion library [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net). If you want to use Pocketsphinx directly, you can find keyword activation implementation in kws branch in subversion (branches/kws)

Comment: Thanks, we'll have to consider that approach, but it adds an extra step for the user that we want to avoid. They now need to tell Siri to launch the app and it would be best if we just go right into speech recognition since there is no other reason to use our app. But perhaps this would acceptable, it requires some study and consideration. We had looked at CMUSphinx, but have been told that it is not actively supported. Have you used it? And OpenEars? The docs suggest it needs training, is that right?

Comment: Both openears and CMUSphinx have way better support than any commercial toolkits. You can check questions tagged with cmusphinx here to get the idea about that. Training is not required.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay, but we've decided to skip CMUSphinx at this point. The team is all fresh graduates with me pitching in as the experienced one as needed, and it looked like more effort than we could afford with such a short runway to get the app going. The commercial packages we've looked at are all one click to download and drag and drop to install and have simple APIs. If the app gets traction we will come back and spend the time to do a deep evaluation of CMUSphinx to try avoiding fees. For now it is a better business decision to use a commercial solution.